# how to resolve this interpolate error

Tags: angularjs

My Code is working fine but console shows the error for interpolate:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{expression}} {{date_expression | date : 'mediumDate'}} TypeError: date is undefined
```

`{{expression}}` 
giving its right result and

`{{date_expression | date :'mediumDate' }}` 
shows correct date in the right format `Sep 3, 2015`

This is the method which I am using:-

```
$scope.formatDate = function(date){
      // var date = '030915',
      day = date.substring(0, 2),
      month = date.substring(2, 4),
      year = date.substring(4, 6);
  var dateOut = new Date('20' + year, month - 1, day);
          return dateOut;
    }
<div> {{item.origin}} {{formatDate(item.departuredate) | date : 'mediumDate' }} 
</div>
```

here item.departuredate = "030915".
It is working fine but shows interpolate error.
Thanks

but I want to remove this error from the console. Someone could help me to resolve this problem.
Thankyou

Comment: can you replicate this on fiddle or plunker ?

Comment: I am getting JSON by a REST service call which is giving date in "030915"
where 03-dd, 09-mm and 15-year. It is giving correct output but console is showing error for intarpolate that date is note defined when i am using filter after calling dateformat method to generate date-object for incomming JSON date.

Comment: Have you assigned $scope.date_expression="" intially ?

Comment: yes. It is working fine when I am using only date interpolate symbol but its showing error when I put another inerpolate symbol just before the date_expression

Comment: @Arunchauhan, show more of your code, specifically where the values are assigned

Comment: @Arunchauhan I didn't get any error here is plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/YTSCRJidJ84F3kUNMK30